# wandb - RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, simpletransformers

I'm trying to run the model given in the hyperparameter optimization [example](https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/tips-and-tricks/#6-putting-it-all-together) from the simple transformers documentation, but while searching for hyperparameters after a certain number of iterations, a CUDA out of memory error occurs. Also during the search for hyperparameters GPU Memory Allocated is constantly increased.

Here is a graph of memory allocation:

[image]

Here's my code. Code I'm launching on Google Collab. How I can fix this error?

```py
import logging

import pandas as pd
import sklearn

import wandb
from simpletransformers.classification import (
    ClassificationArgs,
    ClassificationModel,
)

sweep_config = {
    "method": "bayes",  # grid, random
    "metric": {"name": "train_loss", "goal": "minimize"},
    "parameters": {
        "num_train_epochs": {"values": [2, 3, 5]},
        "learning_rate": {"min": 5e-5, "max": 4e-4},
    },
}

sweep_id = wandb.sweep(sweep_config, project="Simple Sweep")

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
transformers_logger = logging.getLogger("transformers")
transformers_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

# Preparing train data
train_data = [
    ["Aragorn was the heir of Isildur", "true"],
    ["Frodo was the heir of Isildur", "false"],
]
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_data)
train_df.columns = ["text", "labels"]

# Preparing eval data
eval_data = [
    ["Theoden was the king of Rohan", "true"],
    ["Merry was the king of Rohan", "false"],
]
eval_df = pd.DataFrame(eval_data)
eval_df.columns = ["text", "labels"]

model_args = ClassificationArgs()
model_args.reprocess_input_data = True
model_args.overwrite_output_dir = True
model_args.evaluate_during_training = True
model_args.manual_seed = 4
model_args.use_multiprocessing = True
model_args.train_batch_size = 16
model_args.eval_batch_size = 8
model_args.labels_list = ["true", "false"]
model_args.wandb_project = "Simple Sweep"

def train():
    # Initialize a new wandb run
    wandb.init()

    # Create a TransformerModel
    model = ClassificationModel(
        "roberta",
        "roberta-base",
        use_cuda=True,
        args=model_args,
        sweep_config=wandb.config,
    )

    # Train the model
    model.train_model(train_df, eval_df=eval_df)

    # Evaluate the model
    model.eval_model(eval_df)

    # Sync wandb
    wandb.join()


wandb.agent(sweep_id, train)
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you are logging the losses (*something like `wandb.log({...})` maybe?*)?

Comment: I'm not logging the losses, I just tried to run the code from the example. Maybe because I don't do it and there is such an error?

Comment: How many agents do you have running simultaneously? Have you tried running a single run with this model without wandb, as standalone?

Comment: Without wandb, this model works correctly, only 1 session works at a time.

Comment: Have you tried using `del model`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.

Comment: did you solve this? I'm having the same problem